# socket.io disconnect leaves player sprite behind

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, multiplayer

Upon a user disconnecting, the disconnecting player's sprite is still left behind on the other users screens. I'm not sure why.

EDIT: It's fixed. I had duplicate socket events when players joined.

Server side:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      removePlayer(self, socket.id);
      delete players[socket.id];
      io.emit('disconnect', socket.id);
    });

function removePlayer(self, playerId) {
  self.players.getChildren().forEach((player) => {
    if (playerId === player.playerId) {
      player.destroy();
    }
  });
}
```

Client side:

```
this.socket.on('disconnect', function (playerId) {
    self.players.getChildren().forEach(function (player) {
      if (playerId === player.playerId) {
        player.destroy();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: A simple bit of debugging would be to do some logging to see what `playerId` actually is, and logging each `player.playerId` in the forEach loop, too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yep. Good idea. Taking a look now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans by following that, it looks like my client side is logging duplicate IDs for the same player. So that points me to what I should be fixing.